# MVC3: Session_Start Fires twice when testing for Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I need to do some authentication for a web app with MVC3.  The customer would like there to be a generic page to show if they do not have any of the role groups in windows AD that are allowed to use the app.  I found a pretty simple way to do it, but just curious if it is a valid way or if there is something better out there.

Basically in the Session_Start in the global I am checking for User.IsInRole() and if that returns false then I do a Response.Redirect(). This question is: after it his the code in the IF statement and hits the Response.Redirect() code then it hits the session one more time before it goes to the AccessDenied page in the root of the app.  Is this okay?  Will it cause any issues If they are valid and does not enter the If to do the response.redirect?

```
        //if (!User.IsInRole("test_user"))
        //{
        //    Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx", true);
        //}
```

Comment: Have you used "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" ?

Comment: Golda - I tried that, but it still hits the Session_Start function twice - and then redirects to the AccessDenied.aspx page.

Comment: Golda - This is the code I added to the .Layout.cshtml file:  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")

Comment: Check whether it declare twice in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to write your Authorization filter for MVC3 and do this type of logic there:

```
public class RoleFilter: AuthorizeAttribute
{     
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!User.IsInRole("test_user"))
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 302;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/AcessDenied.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Also I wouldn't recommend you to use `Response.Redirect` because it aborts current thread.

Comment: And then I would just use [RoleFilter] then I can just use RoleFiler ontop of my function where I want it to fire off?  I need some code to run no matter what in the Session_Start, but then I want to send them to that page if they are not authorized in the app per their role(s).

Comment: And how does it know about FilterContext?

Comment: The you would add [RoleFilter] on controllers that need authorization check.

Comment: Oleksii Aza  - is there a way I can make a new controller that everyone will have access to it even if they do not have a role that I allow for the application or what would I need to do for that?

Comment: What code do you need to run in Session_Start? Does it related to Authorization checking?

Comment: The code will send their UserGroups that they belong to in AD to a text file in the AppData folder.

Comment: For new controllers that doesn't need role check you can simply doesn't add this attribute or try to add [AllowAnonymous], but maybe this anounymous attribute was added in MVC4 though.

Comment: About logic storing information in text file from AppData - I think you can add it in this filter too.

Comment: Oh.. I see what you're saying.. Since I have all the Logging code in the Helper Folder of my app with no restrictions on it, then I can just call the same code from this area to catch when they are not authorized to view the app 100%. I will try all of this and let you know.. Thanks for the suggestions to try.

Comment: Oleksii Aza = appears what you suggested worked to perfection. Thanks again.